# Are modules expected to stabilize over time on Hackage?

Tags: haskell, hackage

To newcomers it might be surprising that many modules on `Hackage` are marked as `experimental`, even modules as basic as [Data.Bool](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Bool.html).

Is there any process or expectation for modules to become `stable` and especially `base`? Should we pay any attention to this tag?

Comment: File a feature request ticket on the GHC Trac. `Data.Bool` is extremely stable.

Comment: For this kind of of question I would ask [/r/haskell](http://reddit.com/r/haskell) or the [haskell-cafe mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/haskell-cafe).

Comment: The Haskell community is very conservative with versioning, many packages don't have a major version. A good review on the state of the Haskell ecosystem can be found [here](https://github.com/Gabriel439/post-rfc/blob/master/sotu.md).

Comment: It's hard to give a definitive answer here. As far as I can tell, nobody pays attention to that particular flag; honestly, it should probably just be removed from Hackage altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Cabal's Stability tags almost defunct now.

So do not pay attention to that, and beware about package's update date and # of vote